# How to Convert IObserable<bool> to bool in Reactive Extension C#

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I want to check if `System.Reactive.IObserable<TElement>` contains any element.
The `Any()` extension method useless as it is expecting to return the `IObserable<bool>` instead of just bool.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? You should *subscribe* to the observable if you want to execute code when an event occurs, *not* check whether an event has occured

Comment: Your right, i have finally changed the approach of looking at the Obserables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `IObservable<bool> IObservable<T>.Any()` extension method is not useless: it gets an observable that emits a `bool` as soon as possible indicating whether the source observable emitted any values or not. This occurs when either of the following two events occurs:

- The source sequence emits `OnCompleted`. In this case it did not emit any values, so the `Any` sequence emits `OnNext(false)` and then `OnCompleted`.
- The source sequence emits `OnNext`.  So the `Any` sequence emits `OnNext(true)` and then `OnCompleted`.

If you want a `bool` instead of an `IObservable<bool>` for the result, you can `await` the `Any` observable in an `async` context.

```
    IObservable<Prizes> prizes = ...;
    bool winner = await prizes.Any();
```